# Local File inclusion in PHP

Tags: php

I have a file called config.php in application root `\var\www\html` and it can be reached at going to `http://abc.efg.com/config.php`

I also have a file called `index.php`, in the same folder which has some code to include the file name from a query string parameter and read from it.

Ex: `include_once($_GET["page"].php)`

I would like to execute a local file inclusion, by passing some php code that would make that include statement print the contents of `config.php`

Comment: If you want the print the contents, you want `readfile` not `include`. But be very careful allowing people to just read files from your server!

Comment: You'd better use a whitelist, otherwise someone can send the path of any script.

Comment: What happens when you try this? How is your query string composed?

Comment: I want to simulate an attack. Mitigation will come later. :)

Comment: `allow_url_include` is off by default. If someone has it on, he deserves beeing hacked.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Even with that setting switched off, the code as shown would allow including a file from anywhere on the file system.

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding here: is your question "why doesn't this code work?" (because your code is in fact invalid), or is it "how would I simulate an attack?" If it's the second, I think that's probably too broad for this site, without a few more details of what you already know, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not advisable to use it in this way because it leaves a flaw in your site so you can just do:

```
if( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']=='config' ) {
    include 'config.php';
}
```

However, your problem was at the level of `.php`, it was necessary to put in string `'.php'`

Comment: While fixing the formatting of your answer, I've made a small change to the actual code: `include` is not a function, so you don't need brackets around the argument. In a few cases, forgetting this can lead to bugs, so I would recommend to always leave them off.